# DatePicker Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Below is an EditorTemplate that renders a Bootstrap datetimepicker with `EditorFor` helpers, the problem I am seeing is with the script section. It works OK for one `DateTimePicker` per view - but since I am using class selector, whenever I use 2 or more `DateTimePicker`s per view it renders duplicate `<script>` sections, confusing the DOM as to on which `TextBox` to invoke the calendar. What am I missing here?

```
   @model DateTime?
   <div class='input-group date datePicker'>
      <span class="input-group-sm">
         @Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("d") : String.Empty)
      </span>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
       $('.datePicker').datetimepicker({
           pickTime: false
       });
   });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you have as you have correctly deduced is that the script block defined in the editor template will run twice when you have two datepickers included in a view; When it is run twice, the plugin's behaviour is not as expected.

One solution to this would be to target only the datepicker input in the editor template in each script block. For example,

```
@model DateTime?
<div class='input-group date datePicker'>
   <span class="input-group-sm">
      @Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("d") : String.Empty)
   </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // target only the input in this editor template
        $('#@Html.IdForModel()').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works! - thank you much. Now, is there a way to render that script once?

Comment: @kermit_xc the script is going to be rendered as many times as the editor template is called. There is a nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Forloop.HtmlHelpers/ that will render the script only once if it is in a separate script file.

Comment: +1 for the ForLoop ScriptContext. I extended it to do the same with .css, StyleContext - very useful for Display and Editor Templates. They do not even need to be in a separate file, using the AddScriptBlock method.

Comment: I would grab the two HtmlHelper files from the source, though, vs through Nuget - they are not very big nor overly complicated - then modify the functions to handle .css.

Answer (score 0):

As far as rendering the script once, what about the following?  It works for me so far.  Any potential issues?

```
Editor Template - DateTime.cshtml

@model System.DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datepicker" })


_Layout.cshtml

<script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "/Images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });
   }
</script>
```